# Power series representation of the function

Tags: calculus, power-series

I came across this question

> Use a power series representation for the function $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to
>   write a power series representation for the function $\frac{4
> x^3}{(1-x)^2}$, for $-1 < x < 1$

So my question is this:

I know that it's $$4x^3\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
And I know that $$\int \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{(1-x)}$$ which means 
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(1-x)}$$
and $$ \frac{1}{(1-x)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

But I'm not sure mathematically how to continue without ruining it,
because basically what I was thinking is maybe this works:

$$4x^3\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(1-x)}$$
$$4x^3\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
$$4x^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty n  {x^n}^{-1}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4n  {x^n}^{+2}$$

But I'm sure I've done something wrong, please let me know what it is and how I should go about solving this.

Comment: This is quite hand-wavy in some parts (you omit the indices of the summation and exchange the derivation and summation without explain why you can do that) but it is essentially correct.

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga Edited! Thank you.

Comment: The way you edited the indices is not correct, and you still did not explain why you are allowed to perform derivation before summation.

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga That's mainly why I'm asking, because I'm not sure if I could do that in the first place. In terms of the indices I just copied them from the book, so I'm also not sure why they're incorrect.

Comment: Go straight to the point, there is no need to mention an integral. $4x^3/(1-x)^2=4x^3(1/(1-x))'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way of doing this computation. You correctly pointed out that: $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$

so:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^kx^{n-k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$$

This series is convergent since it is the Cauchy product of two absolutely convergent series.

Now we can complete using the same reasoning you used:
$$4x^3\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} = 4x^3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4(n+1)x^{n+3}$$

To answer your question in the comments, you cannot easily exchange differentiation and summation since you require uniform convergence of the derivatives, which in this case you don't have.

**Edit:**

Since you haven't seen the Cauchy product we can do it with the monotone convergence theorem. Call $f_m(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{m}(n+1)x^n$ and $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$, then $$\int f_m(x)dx = \int \sum_{n=0}^{m}(n+1)x^n dx = \sum_{n=0}^{m}\int(n+1)x^n dx$$ since this time the sum is finite and we have no problem integrating term by term. Now if we manage to prove $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int(n+1)x^n dx = \lim_{m\to\infty} \int f_m(x) dx = \int f(x) dx = \int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n dx $$ we will have that $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$$ and then we will be able to proceed as before.

To do this we apply the dominated convergence theorem, and since clearly $f_m(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (-1, 1)$ we just need to show that $f \geq f_m$:

$$f - f_m = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n - \sum_{n=0}^{m}(n+1)x^n = \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$$

which is just the original series up to rearrangement, so it is also greater than $0$ and we are done.

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation, unfortunately we haven't learned how to multiply power series, so I wouldn't know how to use this.

Comment: I hope you know what dominated convergence is, otherwise I don't know how else to show what you want without knowing what tools you are allowed to use.

Comment: I unfortunately don't...all we've learned so far is that there is possibility of differentiating or integrating the power series to solve it.

Comment: Then you are probably expected to just differentiate the power series without thinking too much about why you're allowed to do it.

Comment: Just to make sure in the end, my answer was correct with all the current information I have?

Comment: Not entirely, when you differentiate the series you cannot start with $0$ anymore, you have to start at $1$. You should make a change of variable to solve this issue. Hence why my series has $n+1$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much for your time and patience.